# Offline setting account expiration

Tags: yocto, accounts

I need to set up an account inactivity expiration date (es. 1 year).

As shown in [some tutorials](https://melvingeorge.me/blog/set-expiry-date-for-user-account-linux), a way of doing so is to use the `usermod` command.

Due to some constraints, I need to do so offline, modifying some configuration file before running my embedded (`poky`) distro.

What changes in which configuration file should I apply to have the same effects of such `usermod` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is set in 8th field in `/etc/shadow` (see `man 5 shadow`).

> **account expiration date**
>
> The date of expiration of the account, expressed as the number of days since Jan 1, 1970 00:00 UTC.
>
> Note that an account expiration differs from a password expiration. In case of an account expiration, the user shall not be
> allowed to login. In case of a password
> expiration, the user is not allowed to login using her password.
>
> An empty field means that the account will never expire.

You can compute expiration date using `expr $(date +%s ) / 86400` which will give you number of days since 1/1/1970, then adding whatever days you want.

Note that this will disable user loging after expiration date (as explained above), but will not kill/disable any running unix process.